# Modeling a rolling cube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, simulations

I want to model a behavior of a rolling cube.

So far I managed to calculate the cube position for a given rotation angle. I need to rotate it around the center of gravity, thus I needed to calculate the horizontal and vertical displacement as a function of the current rotation angle.

[image: Rotating cube displacement]

When I apply a given rotation I get proper linear movement. [Video](https://youtu.be/x_QNvXMFpSk).

*To be honest I was suprised how complicated are equations for these values.*

Now I figured it would be nice to give the rotation animation a realistic feeling. By that I mean that the first 45 degrees would be slow at first and accelerating over time, and the second 45 degrees of the rotation would be a free fall.

From what I remember I need to:

1. Figure out what forces interact with the object.
   I know there must be gravity, external(moving) force and the friction.
2. Find out what is the net force rotating the object.
3. Calculate angular acceleration.
4. Derive the equation for the angle as a function of time.

First of all, is this procedure correct?
Second of all, can you help me get started with the `forces` part. I don't really know where to begin, how to apply friction(I assume the rotation happens without any slide).

- Do I hook the gravity force in the center of gravity(I suppose yes)?
- Do I hook the *moving* force in the top-left corner or in the center of gravity? If in the corner, how do I take the torque into account?
- How to I divide these forces into components to calculate net forces in each direction?

I was playing with a carton of juice for half an hour, but I cannot figure out how these forces distribute.

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Very nice video, the shadows really look well, you might think of a 50 percent reduction in the diagram, (using picresize.com or somesuch) it takes ages to scroll down on a phone and personally, I don't think it needs to be that big. Best of luck with it.

Comment: This is a complicated problem and I've tried to model it myself. Here's just **one** complication you'll have to accomodate somehow:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/217025/ . Good luck (I might answer **some** of your questions later on). Nice video!

Comment: @CountTo10 sorry about that, it's 30kB image, I didn't think it would be a problem. Video generated by 3DS Max with default Shadow Map setting.

Comment: Do you assume finite friction, or infinite friction (no-slip)?

Comment: Cool video. What did you use for rendering?

Comment: @ja72 I think I've mentioned it, I assume no slip, so infinite friction. For rendering I used 3DS Max. It's a very powerful tool, also free for students.

Comment: Related : [Why does this rotating cube move forward on impact?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/206518)

Comment: How are you forcing the cube. Is it just momentum carrying over the edge, or is there an active force acting? If yes, where is this force applied?

Comment: @ja72 I would probably assume a force applied at the edge oposing the edge that contacts the floor.

Comment: That doesn't sound it will result in realistic motion. Under what scenario do you have a _constant_ force applied on the edge of an object?

Comment: @ja72 Yes, I suppose

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that at the angle $\alpha=0$, the cube bounces off the floor with no dissipation of energy. Recall that as you say, the rotation happens without any slide. The energy of the cube (kinetic plus potential) is thus conserved and no external force is needed to maintain its motion.

For this kind of problems, it is convenient to use the Lagrangian formalism of mechanics of constrained systems. Indeed, the problem can be reduced to the motion of the center of mass that is forced to move only along quart-circles; we only need not to forget to consider also the rotational kinetic energy.

Let us introduce the angle $\beta$ which is more natural to the system:

$$\beta := \alpha + \frac{\pi}{4}$$

As the motion is going to be "periodical", we will consider only $\beta \in \big(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3}{4}\pi\big)$, which correspond to the configurations between "lying on the side" and "lying on the adjacent side". This system is actually a *physical pendulum*, although inverted (with the center of mass above the pivot).

To find the equation of motion, express the vertical and horizontal coordinates of the center of mass in terms of $\beta$ and the side of the cube, $l$:

$$x = -\frac{l}{\sqrt{2}}\,\cos\beta, \quad y = \frac{l}{\sqrt{2}}\,\sin\beta$$

Compute their time derivatives to obtain the square of the velocity:
$$\dot{x} = \tfrac{l}{\sqrt{2}}\,\dot{\beta}\sin\beta$$
$$\dot{y} = \tfrac{l}{\sqrt{2}}\,\dot{\beta}\cos\beta$$
$$v^2 = \dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 = \frac{l^2}{2}\,\dot{\beta}^2$$

Knowing the moment of inertia of the cube
$$I = \frac{ml^2}{6}\,,$$
express the kinetic and potential energy
$$T = \frac{1}{2}\left(mv^2 + I\dot{\beta}^2\right) = \frac{ml^2}{3}\,\dot{\beta}^2$$
$$V = mgy = \frac{mgl}{\sqrt{2}}\,\sin\beta$$
to get the Lagrangian $L = T - V$.

The Lagrange equation for our degree of freedom $\beta$ reads:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}L}{\mathrm{d}\dot{\beta}} - \frac{\mathrm{d}L}{\mathrm{d}\beta} = 0$$

Specifically,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left(\frac{2ml^2}{3}\,\dot{\beta}\right) + \frac{mgl}{\sqrt{2}}\,\cos\beta = 0$$

or, in other words

$$\ddot{\beta} = -\frac{3}{2\sqrt{2}}\frac{g}{l}\,\cos{\beta}$$

This is essentially the equation of the *mathematical pendulum*. It can be integrated to reduce the order by one:
$$\dot{\beta}^2 + \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{g}{l}\,\sin\beta + C = 0$$

and solved either explicitly using special functions, or numerically.

**Edit:** In order for the cube to get over the edge and actually roll instead of rocking, one needs to choose sufficiently high initial velocity, encoded in C.

Comment: Very impressive looking, but from your equations for $x$ and $y$, this cube appears not to be rolling but rocking backwards and forwards. The first sentence of the question asks for rolling cubes.

Comment: In order for the cube to get over the edge and actually roll instead of rocking, one needs to choose sufficiently high potential velocity, encoded in $C$. As stated in the answer, the solution is valid only in the region $\beta \in \big(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3}{4}\pi\big)$ that corresponds to the configurations between "lying on the edge" and "lying on the adjacent edge".

Comment: This is 'nice math' based on unworkable assumptions. And your edit is a silly cop out. This is misinformation, nicely packaged. -1 from me.

Comment: @SuzuHirose: Thank you, I think I see your point: I had swapped vertical and horizontal directions. Now it should be correct.

Comment: *"Indeed, the problem can be reduced to the motion of the center of mass that is forced to move only along quart-circles"*... Except of course that that doesn't happen. See the link in my comment to the question.

Comment: @Gert: The OP explicitely says that the rotation is to happen without any slide. So the floor is assumed to response with friction in both positive and negative horizontal direction (which is quite realistic, irrespective of that is what the OP asks). The question you are talking about discusses a different situation: there, the friction can have only positive horizontal direction (as it is carried out by the ledge).

Comment: So what happens to the cube's kinetic energy when it hits the floor (w/o sliding)? It simply vanishes? OP's starting point is unrealistic, it would take a complex set of forces to make a cube 'roll' the way the video does. You've derived the equation of motion of a pendulum, nothing more.

Comment: @Gert: The energy (potential + kinetic) is conserved: When the cube hits the floor, it bounces in an ellastic manner and the motion repeats. And yes, the system with these assumptions is a physical pendulum, as I have stated early in the answer.

Comment: *"And yes, the system with these assumptions is a physical pendulum, as I have stated early in the answer"* So no rolling. See Suzu Hirose's comment. And it''s contradictory to your edit, which suggests that if initial velocity is high enough, rolling will occur anyway! :-(

Comment: @trosos Hi, I'm not familiar with the Lagrange equation. I will read more about it and get back to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: With sufficient initial velocity, rolling happens. The system is a pendulum only between two bounces. After a bounce, the motion repeats, only with the cube shifted.

Comment: You mean it bounces from the 'left' to the'right', then back and so forth. That's not rolling. And how much money are you willing to bet you could demonstrate that *empirically*? ;-)

Comment: @Gert: No, the collision would resemble what we would call rolling, ie. the sign of the horizontal component of the cube's momentum would not change. The collision could not affect the horizontal component of momentum, regardless of whether friction takes place or not. The collision forces are infinite (they change momentum in zero time), while friction forces (that prevent the cube to slide) could not be infinite IMO.

Comment: If, as you do, you consider the cube tethered at its pivotal point, there is no horizontal momentum. The *tangential velocity vector* points down, 100 % vertically, at the moment of impact.

Comment: @Gert: Just before the moment of impact, the angle between *total momentum* and the floor is $45^\circ$.

Comment: What do you mean by *total momentum*? Total of which terms?

Comment: Total momentum as in the momentum conservation principle. The sum of momenta of all pieces of the cu

Answer (score 2):

This is a complex problem, so rather than try an suggest an all encompassing solution, let's just look at the forces in play:

[image: Rolling cube]

In red is the force vector we'll make to act as the driving force $F$, in black gravity, in green the Normal force and in purple the friction force (none are to scale).

Firstly, with no other forces acting in the $y$-direction (vertical), the Normal force is always the floor's reactive force (needed to prevent the cibe from sinking into the floor) to gravity:

$$F_N=mg$$

Friction will now resist movement in the $x$-dirrection (horizontal) and it's usually modelled as:

$$F_F=\mu F_N=\mu mg,$$
where $\mu$ is a friction coeficient.

In order to prevent sliding:

$$F_F>F\implies \mu>\frac{F}{mg}$$
$F$ and $mg$ now exert *opposing* torques about the pivot point $P$, with *net* torque:

$$\big(\tau_{net}\big)_{\alpha=\pi/2}=Fa-mg\frac{a}{2}$$

If $\tau_{net}>0$ then clockwise angular acceleration will occur.

This allows us also to further define $\mu$, as the *limit* case is:

$$F=\mu mg \:\text{and }F=\frac{mg}{2}$$

So the minimum value is:

$$\mu>0.5$$

The angular acceleration is more easily treated as a conservation of energy problem, as the work done by $\tau_{net}$ is equal the change in (rotational) *kinetic energy* $\Delta K$:

$$W=\int_{\pi/2}^0\tau_{net}(\alpha)d\alpha=\Delta K$$

From trigonometry:

$$\tau_{net}(\alpha)=F\sqrt{2}a\sin\big(\alpha +\frac{\pi}{4}\big)-mg\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}a\sin\Big(\alpha-\frac{\pi}{4}\Big)$$

On integrating we have:

$$W=\sqrt{2}aF=\frac12 I\omega^2$$

(The $mg$ term drops out because there's no change in potential energy $U$ over $\pi/2\to 0$)

So  at the end of the 'tumble':

$$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{2\sqrt{2}aF}{I}}$$

But as the cube now has kinetic energy and the tangential velocity vector is pointing straight down, the cube has to *rebound*. Neither friction nor the force $F$ can prevent that.

Comment: Note that as the cube rises up there is a vertical acceleration of the CofM so the normal force increases... and once it goes past vertical it accelerates down and the normal force decreases. So your calculation of the minimum coefficient of friction required is not complete.

Comment: The behavior will depend on elastic properties of the surface, correct? If we agree on this, isn't it true that the problem is ill-posed without specification of properties of the surface?  In this solution, what are the assumptions for the surface properties?

Comment: The assumption is a perfectly hard surface.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

1. Accumulate the rotation of the center of mass.
2. Compute tip or slip. If it slips, then it won't accumulate rotation but will slide instead.
3. After the rotation, convert it all back into translation for the next tip or slip computation (where it will reconvert back into possible rotation again) (that gets the sliding ruler problem.)

But this is only approximate thinking, however, its nice and you could apply it to any shape in general.